# Transfering H1B from academia to industry

Tags: working-visas, eu-citizens, greencard, h1-visa

I am currently renewing my H1B visa for another 3 years working for the University. Since I am finishing master's this time next year (at the same University), I am looking into finding a job in industry. I will still have cca 2.5 years left on my 6 years total H1B at the time of applying for jobs. Can I just transfer my visa or there are some restrictions to it? I heard something about how universities can apply for H1B at any time, but industry only once a year (April-May).

Comment: Universities (as non-profits) aren't subject to the annual cap on H-1B visas, while industrial employers are.  Since this cap is hit within a few hours of the window opening each year, it's much harder for an industry employer to sponsor you for a visa.